# How to get the current window name in bash inside screen

Tags: shell-script, gnu-screen

In gnu screen I can set the window title using `Ctrl-a Shift-a <name>`. When I am inside bash prompt I can determine whether I am inside screen by checking the variable `$STY`. Can I check some variable and determine the name of the currently open window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not a variable for the current window title, but `$WINDOW` has the window number which I believe can be used in any command that takes the title.

If you just want to see the window title, then `C-a N` (Ctrl+a,N) will show the current window number and (title) in the message line (typically appears in the bottom left for a couple of seconds and disappears).